Unable to run mvn docker build
Whenever I attempt to build the project I am getting an error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.1:build (default-cli) on project ams-reporting: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load FFI provider com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider: ExceptionInInitializerError: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/h2/cw3c23xn69l8038t381p6vx8sjclfr/T/jffi1874361859365756799.dylib'
I am on a mac m1, running v14. I cannot change the com.spotify plugin in pom file because it conflicts with the rest of the project configuration
I have tried changing the arm64 in terminal but issue persist

did u sudo or chown

The verison of docker-maven-plugin is about 4 years old... maybe it's simply not working with M1 ... Are really needed to use docker-maven-plugin? Can you use something different? For what kind of project?

I didn't do neither, I just ran mvn docker:build from the project folder @Ali.Mojtahed
